# Need help calling table row and cell by index, in a ul list used for sorting

Tags: javascript

I have a function that allows you to search a  list, When a match is found it hides all

and only shows the matches. Each li contains a table. It works fine, except I need to be able to search by table row and cell.

Right now if you search for say the word "red", it shows all tables with red. I want to show only the tables that have "red" in the row and cell that I pass to the search. In other words, search for red in all tables that have it in row 1 cell 1.

I hope I explained that clearly.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is a LSFiddle link to see how it currently works:
https://jsfiddle.net/t205sx7d/

Thanks Mike.

```
<html>

<head>
<title>edit</title>

</head>

<body bgcolor="white" text="black" link="blue" vlink="purple" alink="red" style="font-family:Arial; font-weight:bold; font-size:12pt;">

<p>&nbsp;<input type="text" id="searchbox"> <input type="button" value="search" onclick = "DbSearch(searchbox.value)"> 
click search with a empty box to show all.</p>


<p>&nbsp;<span id="SearchTxt">Show all</span></p>


<ul id="LsUL">

<li>
<table border="1" cellspacing="0" bordercolordark="white" bordercolorlight="black" width="90%">

<tr>
<td width="970" align="center" colspan="2" style="padding-top:5px; padding-bottom:5px;">

<table cellspacing="4" width="96%" bordercolordark="white" bordercolorlight="black" style="border-width:2px; border-color:blue; border-style:solid;" cellpadding="4" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">

<tr>
<td width="316" bgcolor="#666666"><font color="white"><b>edit</b></font></td>

<td width="316" align="center"><b>id: table 1</b></td>
<td width="316" align="right" bgcolor="#666666"><font color="white"><b>delete</b></font></td>
</tr>

</table>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td width="483">Color 1:</td>
<td width="483">red</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td width="483">Color 2:</td>
<td width="483">blue</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td width="483">Color 3:</td>
<td width="483">green</td>
</tr>

</table>

<br>


<li>
<table border="1" cellspacing="0" bordercolordark="white" bordercolorlight="black" width="90%">

<tr>
<td width="970" align="center" colspan="2" style="padding-top:5px; padding-bottom:5px;">

<table cellspacing="4" width="96%" bordercolordark="white" bordercolorlight="black" style="border-width:2px; border-color:blue; border-style:solid;" cellpadding="4" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">

<tr>
<td width="316" bgcolor="#666666"><font color="white"><b>edit</b></font></td>

<td width="316" align="center"><b>id: table 1</b></td>
<td width="316" align="right" bgcolor="#666666"><font color="white"><b>delete</b></font></td>
</tr>

</table>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td width="483">Color 1:</td>
<td width="483">blue</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td width="483">Color 2:</td>
<td width="483">red</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td width="483">Color 3:</td>
<td width="483">pink</td>
</tr>

</table>

<br>

<li><table border="1" cellspacing="0" bordercolordark="white" bordercolorlight="black" width="90%">

<tr>
<td width="970" align="center" colspan="2" style="padding-top:5px; padding-bottom:5px;">

<table cellspacing="4" width="96%" bordercolordark="white" bordercolorlight="black" style="border-width:2px; border-color:blue; border-style:solid;" cellpadding="4" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">

<tr>
<td width="316" bgcolor="#666666"><font color="white"><b>edit</b></font></td>

<td width="316" align="center"><b>id: table 1</b></td>
<td width="316" align="right" bgcolor="#666666"><font color="white"><b>delete</b></font></td>
</tr>

</table>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td width="483">Color 1:</td>
<td width="483">green</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td width="483">Color 2:</td>
<td width="483">yellow</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td width="483">Color 3:</td>
<td width="483">red</td>
</tr>

</table>

<br>

</ul>


<script>  

  function DbSearch(search) {
  var filter, ul, li, a, i, txtValue, c=0;

  filter = search.toUpperCase();
  ul = document.getElementById("LsUL");
  li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");

  for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
  a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("table")[0];
  txtValue = a.textContent || a.innerText;

  if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) { li[i].style.display = ""; c+=1; }
  else { li[i].style.display = "none"; }
  }

  if (search == "") {SearchTxt.innerHTML = "Showing all records."}
  else {SearchTxt.innerHTML = "Searched: " +search+ " Found: " +c;} 

  }

</script> 




</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you have a table head inside table. What I did is that, on all the rows other than head I have added a class `data`. This indicates that we have data in those rows.

Now every time you search, we look in those data rows of every table. If the row with desired index(1) exists and cell with desired index (1) exists we display the table.

Here is the JSFiddle Demo: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t2gaxdwo/)

Here is the code:

**HTML**

```
<html>
   <head>
      <title>edit</title>
   </head>
   <body bgcolor="white" text="black" link="blue" vlink="purple" alink="red" style="font-family:Arial; font-weight:bold; font-size:12pt;">
      <p>&nbsp;<input type="text" id="searchbox"> <input type="button" value="search" onclick = "DbSearch(searchbox.value)"> 
         click search with a empty box to show all.
      </p>
      <p>&nbsp;<span id="SearchTxt">Show all</span></p>
      <ul id="LsUL">
         <li>
            <table border="1" cellspacing="0" bordercolordark="white" bordercolorlight="black" width="90%">
               <tr>
                  <td width="970" align="center" colspan="2" style="padding-top:5px; padding-bottom:5px;">
                     <table cellspacing="4" width="96%" bordercolordark="white" bordercolorlight="black" style="border-width:2px; border-color:blue; border-style:solid;" cellpadding="4" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
                        <tr>
                           <td width="316" bgcolor="#666666"><font color="white"><b>edit</b></font></td>
                           <td width="316" align="center"><b>id: tb1</b></td>
                           <td width="316" align="right" bgcolor="#666666"><font color="white"><b>delete</b></font></td>
                        </tr>
                     </table>
                  </td>
               </tr>
               <tr class="data">
                  <td width="483">Color 1:</td>
                  <td width="483">red</td>
               </tr>
               <tr class="data">
                  <td width="483">Color 2:</td>
                  <td width="483">blue</td>
               </tr>
               <tr class="data">
                  <td width="483">Color 3:</td>
                  <td width="483">green</td>
               </tr>
            </table>
            <br>
         <li>
            <table border="1" cellspacing="0" bordercolordark="white" bordercolorlight="black" width="90%">
               <tr>
                  <td width="970" align="center" colspan="2" style="padding-top:5px; padding-bottom:5px;">
                     <table cellspacing="4" width="96%" bordercolordark="white" bordercolorlight="black" style="border-width:2px; border-color:blue; border-style:solid;" cellpadding="4" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
                        <tr>
                           <td width="316" bgcolor="#666666"><font color="white"><b>edit</b></font></td>
                           <td width="316" align="center"><b>id: tb2</b></td>
                           <td width="316" align="right" bgcolor="#666666"><font color="white"><b>delete</b></font></td>
                        </tr>
                     </table>
                  </td>
               </tr>
               <tr class="data">
                  <td width="483">Color 1:</td>
                  <td width="483">blue</td>
               </tr>
               <tr class="data">
                  <td width="483">Color 2:</td>
                  <td width="483">red</td>
               </tr>
               <tr class="data">
                  <td width="483">Color 3:</td>
                  <td width="483">pink</td>
               </tr>
            </table>
            <br>
         <li>
            <table border="1" cellspacing="0" bordercolordark="white" bordercolorlight="black" width="90%">
               <tr>
                  <td width="970" align="center" colspan="2" style="padding-top:5px; padding-bottom:5px;">
                     <table cellspacing="4" width="96%" bordercolordark="white" bordercolorlight="black" style="border-width:2px; border-color:blue; border-style:solid;" cellpadding="4" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
                        <tr>
                           <td width="316" bgcolor="#666666"><font color="white"><b>edit</b></font></td>
                           <td width="316" align="center"><b>id: tb3</b></td>
                           <td width="316" align="right" bgcolor="#666666"><font color="white"><b>delete</b></font></td>
                        </tr>
                     </table>
                  </td>
               </tr>
               <tr class="data">
                  <td width="483">Color 1:</td>
                  <td width="483">green</td>
               </tr>
               <tr class="data">
                  <td width="483">Color 2:</td>
                  <td width="483">yellow</td>
               </tr>
               <tr class="data">
                  <td width="483">Color 3:</td>
                  <td width="483">red</td>
               </tr>
            </table>
            <br>
      </ul>
   </body>
</html>
```

**Javascript**

```
function DbSearch(search) {
    var filter, ul, li, a, i, txtValue, c = 0;

    filter = search.toUpperCase();
    ul = document.getElementById("LsUL");
    li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");

    for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
        a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("table")[0];
        var cells = a.querySelectorAll(".data")

        // txtValue = a.textContent || a.innerText;

        if (cells[1]) {                                // The row you want to search
            var cols = cells[1].querySelectorAll("td");
            if (cols[1]) {                             // The col you want to search
                txtValue = cols[1].innerText;
                if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                    li[i].style.display = "block";
                    c += 1;
                } else {
                    li[i].style.display = "none";
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if (search == "") {
        SearchTxt.innerHTML = "Showing all records."
    } else {
        SearchTxt.innerHTML = "Searched: " + search + " Found: " + c;
    }

}
```

*One friendly advice*: Please format your code before pasting here, you can use [HTML formatter](https://www.freeformatter.com/html-formatter.html) and [Javascript formatter](https://www.freeformatter.com/javascript-beautifier.html), or any other tool. Look for formatters or beautifiers online for any language, you will find tools :)

Comment: Thank you very much Ankur, for taking the time to help me out.
It’s people like you who make these forums what they are.
Mike.